# Why array content from php is not inputing to array in js?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a little problem, the point is that my array is not getting content.

```
$staff = array(
"permissions" => false,
"staff" => true,
"group" => 3
);
echo json_encode($staff);
```

```
let staff = [];

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../includes/signin.inc.php",
})
.done(function (data) {
    staff = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(staff);
})
.fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
  alert(status);
});
```

And i have this error:
`Unexpected end of JSON input`

Just i want array $staff place into staff in js.

---

I changed file,

```
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = ? OR email = ?");
    $stmt->execute([$_POST['username'], $_POST['username']]);
    $row = $stmt->fetch();

    if ($row && password_verify($_POST['pwd'], $row['password'])) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['user'] = $row['username'];
        $group = $row['permissions'];
        include 'group.inc.php';
        header("Location: ../home/");
    } else {
        echo "invalid";
    }
}
```

And group.inc.php:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

switch ($group) {
    case '0':
        break;
    case '1':
        $_SESSION['permissions'] = false;
        echo json_encode($_SESSION['staff'] = true);
        $_SESSION['group'] = 1;
        break;
    case '2':
        $_SESSION['permissions'] = false;
        echo json_encode($_SESSION['staff'] = true);
        $_SESSION['group'] = 2;
        break;
    case '3':
        $staff = array(
            "permissions" => false,
            "staff" => true,
            "group" => 3
        );
        echo json_encode($staff);
        break;
}
```

In js i changed only path. Of course my new error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

Comment: Is that **$staff** definition and encoding in a script that outputs HTTP properly, or does it just do that `echo`?

Comment: Put a `header('Content-Type: application/json');` at PHP script start.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Does your browser's network console help you to determine whether this is a PHP problem, **or** an JS problem? Usually, it's not both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

before sending your JSON from server to client. Then the error will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys, I checked network in browser and my variables were null.

Now it works, code:

```
$_SESSION['group'] = $row['permissions'];
    include 'group.inc.php';
```

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

session_start();

$group = $_SESSION['group'];

switch ($group) {
    case '0':
        break;
    case '1':
        $_SESSION['permissions'] = false;
        echo json_encode($_SESSION['staff'] = true);
        $_SESSION['group'] = 1;
        break;
    case '2':
        $_SESSION['permissions'] = false;
        echo json_encode($_SESSION['staff'] = true);
        $_SESSION['group'] = 2;
        break;
    case '3':
        $staff = array(
            "permissions" => false,
            "staff" => true,
            "group" => 3
        );
        echo json_encode($staff);
        break;
}
```

```
  console.log(data.group);
  console.log(data.staff);
  console.log(data.permissions);
```

Result:

```
{permissions: false, staff: true, group: 3}
group: 3
permissions: false
staff
```